# A question about Binding Theory

Tags: syntax, theoretical-linguistics, binding-theory

In Binding Theory, Principle B says a pronoun must be free in its binding domain. But I wonder if there are any other constraints? For example, "He says her is great". In this way, "her" is free in binding domain but it is still not grammatical, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding Theory deals with which pronouns can go where, but not which form of a pronoun you use. **Case Assignment** is what determines "she" vs. "her", and the position of the pronoun in "He says she/*her is great", the "she" form (subject/nominative case) can go there, but the "her" form (object/oblique) cannot.

Comment: Your answers would be aesthetically better if italics were used instead of quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!